# Two different relative pronouns within the same sentence

Tags: relative-pronouns

I came across my course-mate's writing, and find a sentence rather disturbing. Thus, I am writing to seek advice regarding the correctness of that sentence as follows:

> If possible, ignore acronyms and other jargon, which renders the title complicated to readers who may not familiarize with the topic.

My main question here is whether it is wrong to have two relative pronouns (in this case, *which* and *who*) used in the same sentence as shown above.

Comment: "That" does not appear in your sentence.

Comment: But "that" and "who" and "which" can appear many times in a sentence. For example: *I want the information **which** John got from the man **who** thought  **that** all dogs bark.* These are not conjunctions.

Comment: Hi @Silenus, sorry for the typo. I mean 'which' and 'who'. I have changed the 'that' into 'which' in my question section by editing. However, my given sentence remains unchanged.

Comment: The short answer is that neither *which* nor *who* are conjunctions, and there is neither any grammatical rule against having two conjunctions in a sentence nor against having two relative pronouns in a sentence. We will be better able to give you a complete answer if you can indicate what rule or guideline made you think otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with your sentence except that *renders* should be *render* (the subject is "acronyms and other jargon*), and *may not familiarize* should be *may not be familiar* (incorrect use of *familiarize*):

> If possible, ignore acronyms and other jargon, which *render* the
>   title complicated to readers who may not be familiar with the topic.

The use of *which* and *who* is entirely grammatical.

Comment: @kjyon2 My pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to avoid the use of both. The sentence is confusing because "which renders" is singular and therefore refers only to the jargon and not to the acronyms. I suspect the writer intended "which render", thereby referring to acronyms and jargon together.